# Woocommerce Session cookie not set on ajax when using admin-ajax.php

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress ajax function which is using the **WC()->session** to take session data and use it in the function. *(for exmaple taking chosen shipping method from the session and displaying it)*.

The function is working properly on my local machine. However, it's not working on **WP Engine live server**. I have already contacted them and they advised that the issue should not be on their side.

As far as I can see the following cookies are not being set on the live server only for admin-ajax.php request:

- Set-Cookie: `woocommerce_items_in_cart`
- Set-Cookie: `woocommerce_cart_hash`
- Set-Cookie: `wp_woocommerce_session`

Does anyone have any idea what might cause this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is not normal and seems to be related to WP Engine hosting.

Now you should try to force enable Woocommerce Customer Session (if it's not enabled yet), with the following code that will set the `WC_Session` cookie.

It could enable back `WC()->session` when using `admin-ajax.php`:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'enable_wc_session_cookie' );
function enable_wc_session_cookie(){ 
    if( is_admin() )
       return;

    if ( isset(WC()->session) && ! WC()->session->has_session() ) 
       WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true ); 
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It could works.

Answer (score 0):

With the accepted answer you will have a session on all pages, which leads to some problems like disabling cache or slower page loads for first-time visitors, Woocommerce itself sets this cookie on-demand and when it's needed and destroys it once it's not needed anymore, i think you should follow the same strategy, set the cookie via one of below methods, and destroy it once you're done with it. (for example when the order payment is completed)

```
WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );
// OR
do_action('woocommerce_set_cart_cookies', true);
```